# How to set some weights in a layer in Keras

Tags: python, keras

Is there a way to set particular weights to be a specific value in Keras layers?

For example, I have a set of 3x3 numpy arrays as input. They are arranged in sequences of 7. Each array has values 0, 1, or -1. For positions with the value -1, I want there to be no contribution to weight calculations or the loss function. I had thought `Masking` would provide what I was looking for, but that proved to be a dead end: you cannot mask individual values within an input example, as far as I can tell.

Is there a way to use `set_weights` to accomplish this?

This code is what I have so far (no `set_weights` yet).

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from keras.optimizers import adam

#Creating some sample data

#Matrix has size 3*3, values -1, 0, 1
X = np.random.rand(3, 3).flatten()
X[X < 0.2] = 0.
X[(X >= 0.2) & (X < 0.4)] = 1.
X[X >= 0.4] = -1

X2 = np.random.rand(7, 3*3)
for i in range(X2.shape[0]):
    X2[i,:][(X==-1.)] = -1.
    X2[i,:][(X !=-1.)] = 0.
    tobeone = int(len(np.where(X2[i,:] == 0.)[0])*0.5)
    selected_ones = np.random.choice(np.where(X2[i,:] == 0.)[0], tobeone)
    X2[i,selected_ones] = 1.

X = np.reshape(X, ((1, 3*3)))
X_new = np.concatenate((X, X2), axis=0)
y_true = X_new[7,:]
X = X_new[:7,:]

#Building the model

input_tensor = Input(shape=(7, 3*3))
lstm = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)(input_tensor)
output = Dense(3*3, activation='sigmoid')(lstm)

model = Model(input_tensor, output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

**EDIT**

Now with 500 training examples, slightly modified the model for dimension purposes (now without return_sequences=True - I needed that when I was experimenting with `Masking`, but now it's not necessary). Please keep in mind these data are random, so we're not expecting a good fit here.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.optimizers import adam
import sys

#Creating some sample data

#Matrix has size 3*3, values -1, 0, 1
X = np.random.rand(7, 3, 3).flatten() #7*3*3 = 42
X[X < 0.2] = 0.
X[(X >= 0.2) & (X < 0.4)] = 1.
X[X >= 0.4] = -1

Xlist = list()
Xlist.append(X)
for j in range(499): #500 total input examples
    X2 = np.random.rand(7, 3, 3).flatten()
    X2[(X==-1.)] = -1.
    X2[(X !=-1.)] = 0.
    tobeone = int(len(np.where(X2 == 0.)[0])*0.5)
    selected_ones = np.random.choice(np.where(X2 == 0.)[0], tobeone)
    X2[selected_ones] = 1.
    X2 = np.reshape(X2, ((7, 3, 3)))
    Xlist.append(X2)

Xlist[0] = np.reshape(Xlist[0], ((7, 3, 3)))
X = np.asarray(Xlist)
X = np.reshape(X, ((500, 7, 3*3)))

Y = X[:, -1, :]
y_true = Y
X = X[:, :-1, :]

#print(y_true.shape, X.shape) #(500, 9) and (500, 6, 9)

#Building the model
input_tensor = Input(shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))
lstm = LSTM(1)(input_tensor) #return_sequences=True)(input_tensor)
output = Dense(X.shape[2], activation='sigmoid')(lstm)

model = Model(input_tensor, output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X, y_true, batch_size = 10, epochs = 10, verbose=2)
```

Comment: You may be able to subclass the weight regularizer type to create your own dependent on input values of -1: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/regularizers.py#L66. You'd probably want to change the __call__ method, where regularization is calculated.

Comment: Hi @AriK, thanks for the suggestion. If you could write it up as an answer with relevant code building on my example, I'd really appreciate it. I don't really understand your suggestion yet.

Comment: I'll work on one

Comment: Have you tested if your architecture trains? The lstm dimensions don't work for me. (Maybe I'm passing in the wrong data: X, y_true)

Comment: It won't train because there's only one input sequence - there's not really anything to train on. I can modify the code and get back to you. Thanks again for taking a look at this!

Comment: Alright thanks! I think it won't matter for the regularizer example I'm trying to implement so I'll continue working on it with a different architecture. And np!

Comment: @AriK It's up! Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was in using the weights as a Variable type, instead of using the values inside. This was fixed via setting `weights = K.eval(weights)` in `custom_reg`.

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.ops.variables import Variable
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.optimizers import adam
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback


class SaveWeightsandRegularize(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    # Batch_num is defined so we can access the current X input into the model, as well as save layer params per batch.

    batch_num = 0
    X = None  # We'll set this to our X data

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.weights = {}

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.batch_num += 1
        for layer in model.layers:
            self.weights[str(self.batch_num)] = layer.get_weights()

    def custom_reg(self, weights):
        # We set the already computed weights where the value of the input is -1 to a value of 0.
        weights = K.eval(weights)
        loss_contrib = np.where(X[self.batch_num] > -1, weights, 0)
        return Variable(loss_contrib)

# Creating some sample data


def gen_data():
    # Matrix has size 3*3, values -1, 0, 1
    X = np.random.rand(7, 3, 3).flatten()  # 7*3*3 = 42
    X[X < 0.2] = 0.
    X[(X >= 0.2) & (X < 0.4)] = 1.
    X[X >= 0.4] = -1

    Xlist = list()
    Xlist.append(X)
    for j in range(499):  # 500 total input examples
        X2 = np.random.rand(7, 3, 3).flatten()
        X2[(X==-1.)] = -1.
        X2[(X !=-1.)] = 0.
        tobeone = int(len(np.where(X2 == 0.)[0])*0.5)
        selected_ones = np.random.choice(np.where(X2 == 0.)[0], tobeone)
        X2[selected_ones] = 1.
        X2 = np.reshape(X2, ((7, 3, 3)))
        Xlist.append(X2)

    Xlist[0] = np.reshape(Xlist[0], ((7, 3, 3)))
    X = np.asarray(Xlist)
    X = np.reshape(X, ((500, 7, 3*3)))

    Y = X[:, -1, :]
    y_true = Y
    X = X[:, :-1, :]
    return X, y_true

X, y_true = gen_data()
save_weights_regularize = SaveWeightsandRegularize()
save_weights_regularize.X = X
print("input shape", X.shape)
# Building the model
input_tensor = Input(shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))
lstm = LSTM(1)(input_tensor)  # return_sequences=True)(input_tensor)
output = Dense(X.shape[2], activation='sigmoid',       kernel_regularizer=save_weights_regularize.custom_reg)(lstm)

model = Model(input_tensor, output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y_true, batch_size=1, epochs=10, verbose=2, callbacks=[save_weights_regularize])
print(save_weights_regularize.weights)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this a try! The first time I ran the code, I got a syntax error (it didn't like the '.' in the callback in model.fit). The second time, I got the same error as you did. I see the point of the class was to reassign the weights of all layers to be 0 when the input is -1 in that position - great! In `gen_data`, I changed `X[X >= 0.4] = -1` to `X[X >= 0.4] = -1.`, and changed `0` to `0.` and`-1` to `-1.` in `np.where`, but I still get your error. It seems to expect a string, according to python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Oop, sorry for the syntax error. I will think about this some more and try and make progress. And np, It's an interesting problem